# Standalone html page - rendering in sharepoint

Tags: 2007, css, page-viewer-web-part, rendering

I have a small issue on SP2007.
My goal was to provide some nice, elegant formating on my team site landing page (I am not a site collection administrator), and to do that I did some html page that was loading custom css.

I had a lot of issues to have proper rendering and realized that:

- As a stand alone html file, on my disk, I could open the file in browser and have proper rendering in IE, chrome, firefox.....

When I moved the file to the shared documents library:

- Opening the file in any browser via the webdav interface (windows explorer basically) the rendering was good (exactly as before)
- Opening the file by clicking on the SharePoint document directly from IE gave me an incorrect rendering (the file opened in a different tab and within the SharePoint)
- Integrating the same html file in page viewer webpart, either as a webpage or a file did work but the rendering was incorrect - exactly as what I get when clicking on the file within the library.

Any idea why this is occurring, and how to fix that? 
My gut feelings tell me that I have some css applying but no idea how/why?

Any idea in the community?

Comment: When pages are rendered by the SP server, it uses the master page and layout templates. Your page code is then rendered in within the SharePoint site. You should do some reading on master pages and consider using SharePoint designer to view/edit the pages. This can seem very confusing, to begin with - but once you get your head around how SharePoint renders your pages on the server side, it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help here.
One thing that keep bothering me is the difference that I see when I type:

Comment: Thanks for your help here.
One thing that keep bothering me is the difference that I see when I type:
_http://spserver/site/Shared Documents/test.html
_ \\spserver\site\Shared Documents\test.html
The source code looks similar and in chrome it give the same rendering... in IE it does not and I am struggling with that difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
I apparently found a potential culprit here ... Sp itself and its rendering as IE8. 
So even if I use IE11, I still have to take into acount lack of CSS3 features in IE8 when dealing with sharepoint2007...

Let see how I can work around (pie or rewriting without any css3 features..).